# Eclipse remove comments, break points and fix indentation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I'm using **Eclipse IDE** for **java** and **android** developments. Is there any easy way to do the followings.

- remove **comments**
- remove **break points**
- fix the **indentation** in the code

For me it take a large time to fix them manually as some times I have to look for them. Can some one answer me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To remove comments**  :
To uncomment single line:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
To uncomment multiline <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

**To remove break points:**
On the menu bar, go to  `Run`-> `Remove All Breakpoints`
To remove breakpoint from single line, go the line and toggle breakpoint using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

**To fix the indentation in the code:**
Fix code formatting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot. Short cuts helps a lot.

Comment: @SamanthaWithanage Please accept the answer if it resolves your question properly. Thanks.